# How to set the number of images in ParallelMapDataset datatype in Tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, data-structures, deep-learning

```
dataset, info = tfds.load('oxford_iiit_pet:3.*.*', with_info=True)

train_images = dataset['train']

test_images = dataset['test']

train_batches = ( 
    train_images
    .cache()
    .shuffle(BUFFER_SIZE)
    .batch(BATCH_SIZE)
    .prefetch(buffer_size=tf.data.AUTOTUNE))

test_batches = test_images.batch(BATCH_SIZE)
```

Now I would like to reduce the test_images size to 100 images.
I am expecting some code like:

```
test_images = test_images[100]
```

But this would give an error:

```
'ParallelMapDataset' object is not subscriptable
```

Comment: Does `test_batches = test_images.take((100 // BATCH_SIZE) + 1)` work for you? If you want exactly 100 images, then use `take(100)` first and batch later.

Comment: Ya...It worked...thanks ;)

Comment: @Frightera I kindly suggest you post this as an answer, so that OP can subsequently accept

Comment: @Frightera anytime ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `take()` method you can take batches or items from the target dataset.

If dataset is batched:

```
test_images.take((100 // BATCH_SIZE) + 1)
```

When you batch the dataset, it will contain batches or groups.

So let's say, you batch your data with a size 32, `test_images.take(1)` will return 32 elements, in other words a single batch. `test_images.take(2)` will return 64 elements etc.

---

If it is not batched:

```
test_images.take(100)
```

Unlike batch dataset, the dataset will return the amount of elements that have passed into `take()` method.